# how to add custom NSMenuItem at menuForMenuKind in FinderSync

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create a custom NSMenuItem for a Finder Sync extension in Swift/Cocoa. I have the following code:

```
  override func menu(for menuKind: FIMenuKind) -> NSMenu {
    // Produce a menu for the extension.
    let menu = NSMenu(title: "")

    let v = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
    v.wantsLayer = true
    v.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.cyan.cgColor

    let newItem = NSMenuItem()
    newItem.view = v
    newItem.target = self
    menu.insertItem(newItem, at: 0)
    
    return menu
}
```

But the cyan view does not show in **FinderSync** extension nemu. How can I add a custom view in menuForMenuKind?

Answer (score 1):

There are only a handful of menu item properties being used in Finder Sync Extension, according to the `FIFinderSyncProtocol` header:

> ... Specific menu item properties are used: title, action, image, and enabled. Starting in 10.11: tag, state, and indentationLevel also work, and submenus are allowed.

So the answer is: **No.** You're currently not allowed to use custom view in menu item in a Finder Sync Extension.

---

However, if you're looking for a non-sandboxed hack, although I personally not recommended, @zerodivisi0n has a [wonderful repository](https://github.com/zerodivisi0n/FinderMenu) that inject custom menu item into Finder's context menu.